# CassandraInvalidQueryException String didn't validate Composite Primary Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to use Spring-Data-Cassandra with UserDefinedType and Compound Query Key. I am using 1.5.0.DATACASS-172-SNAPSHOT of the spring-cql and spring-data-cassandra. The code throws below exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraInvalidQueryException: 
String didn't validate.; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: 
String didn't validate.
```

Below is my code

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class EmployeeIdKey implements Serializable {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED,name = "id")
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1,type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, name = "user_id")
    @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT)
    private String userId;

    public EmployeeIdKey(){
        id = null;
        userId = null;
    }

    public UUID getUuId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setUuId(UUID uuId) {
        this.id = uuId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
@Table("employee")
public class Employee {
    @PrimaryKey
    private EmployeeIdKey id;

    private Person person;

    @Column("employee_no")
    private String employeeNo;

    @Column("email_ids")
    private List<String> emailId;
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Person.java

```
@UserDefinedType
public class Person {

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

    }
    @Column("first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column("last_name")
    private String lastName;
// Getters adn setters;
}
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends TypedIdCassandraRepository<Employee,EmployeeIdKey> {
}
```

App.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class);
    }
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo( EmployeeRepository repository) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        EmployeeIdKey key = new EmployeeIdKey();
        key.setUserId("55550");
        key.setUuId(UUID.randomUUID());
        employee.setId(key);
        List<String> emailIds = Arrays.asList("myemail@domain.com","myemail2@domain2.com");
        employee.setEmailId(emailIds);
        Person person = new Person("John", "Mathew");
        employee.setPerson(person);


        repository.save(employee);
        return  null;
    }
}
```

When I use simple primary key it works well.

Comment: The code is correct and User-Type support is merged to `master` since Friday. 

I can't reproduce the issue you mentioned, I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mp911de/b587b5e7396e53a7cd5c00ff9d0e9ab2) containing your code and the current Spring Data Cassandra snapshots.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I think the problem was w.r.t spring-boot version. I am now trying to get ZonedDateTime but I am getting error. Gist of the same is [link here]( https://gist.github.com/allahbaksh/36c7c05c3d39b9391b1238825f284250)

Comment: Sorry, no support for `com.datastax.driver.extras.*` but you can provide your own converter, see [Custom Converters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/cassandra/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/cassandra/convert/ConverterConfiguration.java).